# why selenium test cases are got skipped randomly while running testng.xml in windows cmd

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, testng.xml

I have tried to run the selenium automation test cases using testng.xml file with multiple cases, but some cases got skipped. TestNG not showing skipped testcases count also, but showing total count and failures count. Can't find the reason and resolve this issue.

So i need solution for run the tescases using testng.xml without skipping in windows cmd using following command in cmd line;

```
    java org.testng.TestNG %project_location%\sample_testng.xml
```

Could you please anyone help me on this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your tests weren't skipped. They were successful.

```
Tests run: 19 = Total test count.
Failures: 15 = Failed tests.
Skips: 0 = Skipped tests.
Total test count - Failed tests - Skipped tests = Successful tests.
```

> 19 - 15 - 0 = **4 Successful tests**